# Как переименовать название ключа в массиве? php

Tags: php

Как переименовать название ключа в массиве? php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

например

```html
day = "2019-01-26"
day = "2019-01-27"
day = "2019-01-28"
day = "2019-01-29"
```

Comment: у массива не может быть несколько одинаковых ключей

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Как у вас указано в примере работать не будет, потому что ключ в массиве должен быть уникальный. Вы можете сделать вложенный массив, но тоже с обычной нумерацией.

Например:

```
$dates['day'] = array_values($myDates);

$dates['day'] = [
    '2019-01-26',
    '2019-01-27',
    '2019-01-28',
    '2019-01-29',
];
```

либо вам придется добавлять дополнительные префиксы к ключам:

```
$dates = [];

foreach ($myDates as $key => $date) {
   $dates['day_' + $key] = $date
}

$dates['day'] = [
     'day_20' => '2019-01-26',
     'day_21' => '2019-01-27',
];
```

Но то как вы хотите собрать массив не получится, потому что при любых манипуляциях с одинаковым ключом вы получите только последнее значение, предыдущие перетрутся.

```
$dates = [];

foreach ($myDates as $date) {
    $dates['day'] = $date;
}

$dates['day'] = "2019-01-26" // перетрется
$dates['day'] = "2019-01-27" // перетрется
$dates['day'] = "2019-01-28" // перетрется
$dates['day'] = "2019-01-29" // останется
```

Вам стоит почитать [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

Ключи массива должны быть уникальными и следовательно всех их `day` не назовешь.

Если же просто нужно переименовать ключ, то можно так:

```
$a = [
    '11' => 'ab',   
    '12' => 'cd',   
    '13' => 'ef'
];

function renameKey(&$array, $old, $new) {
    $s = $array[$old];
    unset($array[$old]);
    $array[$new] = $s;
}

renameKey($a, '12', '12new');

print_r($a);
```